# Ajax get redirect url from 403 error

Tags: ajax, url-routing, redirect

I'm making an ajax call to get a JSON response from the Soundcloud API. The issue I'm having is that some tracks are forbidden (error 403) to access. But I still want to obtain the URL where the GET request ended up at, since it holds the track id within it which I want to get. Here's the code:

```
function getSoundcloudId(url, callback) {
 $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + url + '&client_id=6d5bc62a483dce12f6f1d01bd93a0608',
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    callback(json);
  },
  complete: function(xhr, textstatus) {
    console.log(textstatus);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());

   },
 });
}
```

I've been experimenting and trying to get the Location from the header which returns null and I cannot find anything within the xhr response that displays the new redirected URL. Where in the Chrome console it alerts me with the redirected url saying that the webpage I'm after is forbidden, I'm not sure if it's any help but it annoyed me seeing that it could find :P.

[Chrome 403 Response with redirect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRMqh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any information back from soundcloud?

It can sometimes be useful to just output the response and see what it says.

I had a quick look at their API, and it looks like you don't need to authenticate for simple GET requests.

I tried "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=6d5bc62a483dce12f6f1d01bd93a0608" in the browser and it gave me a nice response.

Are you sure what you are trying to do, doesn't require authentication?

Comment: I'm after specific tracks, which requires me to authenticate. I have it working for the majority of tracks but there are some tracks that return forbidden 403. Where I have another url to request from that will return the JSON that just has the stream url. If you try 

https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/therealpressplay/sevenyears&client_id=6d5bc62a483dce12f6f1d01bd93a0608

You will get the 403 response from that and if you replace the url for another track it will be fine. Where I want the redirected url from that response.